# Use Laravel Debugbar in production for admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a production site (laravel 5.8) which sometime have bug. This bug are not in local.
SO i wanted to enable barryvdh debugbar but just for admin in production.

I created DebugMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class DebugMiddleware
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next) // permet d'afficher la debugbar en prod
{

    if (auth()->user() && in_array(auth()->id(), [1])) {
     \DebugBar::enable();
    }
    else {
        Debugbar::disable();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

i added this in kernel :

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
......
  \Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\DebugMiddleware::class, /// affiche la debugbar en prod pour l'user 1
```

And in debugbar.php i have :

```
 'enabled' => env('DEBUGBAR_ENABLED', null),
```

The problem is an error

```
Class DebugBar' not found
```

when i try to load any page on the site.

Comment: Bad idea. Just use something like Sentry or just read the logs.

Comment: But the reason this happens is probably because you installed the debugbar as dev dependency and ran composr install with production arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try to use global `app` helper instead of Facade. Hope it helps:

```php
app('debugbar')->disable();
```

and

```php
app('debugbar')->enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the \ before Debugbar or add the deps at the top of middleware.

```
if (auth()->user() && in_array(auth()->id(), [1])) {
 \DebugBar::enable();
}
else {
 \Debugbar::disable(); // make sure use the \ before!
}

return $next($request);
```

Another approach can be:

```
config(['app.debug' => true]); // set laravel debug on true
```

By default **barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** enables with debug on true. The update middleware can be:

```
if (auth()->user() && in_array(auth()->id(), [1])) {
 config(['app.debug' => true]);
}

return $next($request);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

add next on file  "app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php"

```
        if( env('APP_DEBUG') ) {
        \Debugbar::enable();
    }else{
        \Debugbar::disable();
    }
```